# Use sed to remove string results in empty file

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I have large text files, in which sometimes long lines are broken into multiple lines by writing a `=` and then a `newline` character. (Enron email data from Kaggle). Since even words are broken this way and I want to do some machine learning with the data, I'd like to remove those breaks. As far as I can see the combination `=\n` is only used for these breaks, so if I remove those, I have the same information without the breaks and nothing gets lost.

- I cannot use `tr` because it only replaces 1 character, but I have two characters to replace.
- The `sed` command I am using so far to no avail is:

  `sed --in-place --quiet --regexp-extended 's/=\n//g' email_aa_edit`

  where `email_aa_edit` is a part of the enron mail data (used split to split it) and is my input file. However this only produces an empty file and I am not sure why. Afaik `=` is not a special character on itself and the newline should be `\n`.

What is the correct way of removing those `=\n` occurrences?

Comment: I'd use perl: `perl -pi -e 's/=\n//' email_aa_edit`

Comment: @melpomene interesting, I am sure I had the same regex in an attempt to use perl before, but the other parameters were different and it didn't work. Yours did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove newlines characters since sed works line by line, but it's possible if you append the next line to the pattern space:

```
sed ':a;/=$/{N;s/=\n//;ta}' file
```

details:

```
:a; # defines a label "a"
/=$/ { # if the line ends with =
    N; # append the next line to the pattern space
    s/=\n//; # replace the =\n
    ta # jump to label "a" when something is replaced (that's always the case
       # except if the last line ends with =)
}
```

Note: if your file uses the Windows newline sequence, change `\n` to `\r\n`.

Comment: I don't know why, but my input file stays the same, as if that command had no effect at all.

Comment: @Zelphir: add the in-place option (I have written the command without any switch to make it more clear).

Comment: Yes that worked. At least after I figured out, that I have to remove the `--quiet` option from my command : )

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Can you chain pattern and substition in same sed command? Like this --> 's/pattern/{s/pattern/{s/pattern/substition}}'

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: No you can't. But note that it's a strange idea, since if possible it could be reduced to a simple `s/pattern/substitution/`